# DevExpress Xtra Reports Page Break Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtrareport

Working on a project, where I generate graphs dynamically using xtra reports of the dev express suit, and am not bidning the graph to a data source. When I use a datasource to produce labels to test them out, the

```
Detail.PageBreak = DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.PageBreak.AfterBand;
```

works. But if I am generating the labels without a data source, this doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source:[forcing a conditional page break when a label text changes value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q240395.aspx)

To accomplish this task you can either add a GroupFooter band and set the GroupFooter.PageBreak to AfterBand. **or put a XRPageBreak control, handle the Detail.BeforePrint and adjust the visibility of the XRPageBreak as you need.**
  To get processing row you need to use the XtraReport.GetCurrentRow() method.
  Please try this solution, and let us know the results.

You can force a page break on certain conditions. Reference link has an example at the bottom as attachment..

You can also [use the Before_Print event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700812/770710) to accomplish this task.

Hope this help..

Comment: thanks, helped a bit...still not exactly what I'm looking for though